# I need help on integrating matlab code with android

Tags: android, matlab, image-processing

I am doing a image processing project(small one). I am coding algorithms in matlab and testing them in MCR. But my idea is to port this algorithm to my android device build a nice application and implement my concept on the host device, so that the application will be portable and can be used anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to be a bit more specific as there are some MATLAB products that would let you convert a subset of MATLAB into C code that you could later use.

For instance the [MATLAB coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/) which:

> "Generates standalone C and C++ code from MATLAB® code The generated source code is portable and readable. MATLAB Coder supports a subset of core MATLAB language features, including program control constructs, functions, and matrix operations. It can generate MEX functions that let you accelerate computationally intensive portions of MATLAB code and verify the behavior of the generated code".

However, be aware that not every function available in the Image Processing Toolbox can be used in the MATLAB coder:

> "A limited set of functions are supported for code generation from Aerospace Toolbox, Image Processing Toolbox™, and Signal Processing Toolbox™"

So you would need to build your algorithms using that subset in order for you to be able to generate C or C++ code from it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using morphology algorithms to map the different type of leaves. The C code will be integrated to an android application via NDK.